# Likelihood Ratio Criterion in EFA

Tags: factor-analysis, likelihood-ratio

This is in ref to pp. 54-55 in [McDonald,R.P](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=kCLNJnuZQbQC&pg=PA50&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false)[1] in the context of exploratory factor analysis (EFA) ML estimation.
 The likelihood ratio criteria, to me, seems to be performing dual roles: I. Providing a measure to determine the probability that the sample is from a population that conforms to the model II. Providing a measure of discrepancy between the model based estimated (population) correlation matrix and the sample correlation matrix – this discrepancy calculated in terms of straight forward discrepancy between corresponding cells entries in the two matrices. 
What links Roles (I) and (II)? Grateful for reference, preferably at  elementary/conceptual level.

[1] Roderick P. McDonald (1985),
Factor Analysis and Related Methods,
Psychology Press

Answer (score 1):

Fabrigar & Wegener (2011) present a pretty accessible explanation of the likelihood ratio (or $\chi$$^2$) test statistic. In a nutshell, and as you correctly point out, the $\chi$$^2$ statistic is calculated based on the discrepancy between the model-implied and observed correlation matrix; larger values indicate greater misfit between the model and the actual data. The test statistic is then commonly used to perform a hypothesis test evaluating the null-hypothesis of a perfect fitting model (i.e., zero discrepancy between model-implied and observed correlation matrixes); many think this test is theoretically unreasonable, as no models are actually perfect, and the test is sensitive such that you will reject models with trivial misspecification at larger sample sizes.

**References**
Fabrigar, L. R., & Wegener, D. T. (2011). *Exploratory factor analysis*. New York, NY: Oxford University Press.